# Spring MVC RequestParam with optional value

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I have a a request mapping similar to the following:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/init/filter/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public final Reponse filterGrid(
            @RequestParam(value = "nom", required = false) final String nom,
            @RequestParam(value = "matricule", required = false) final String matricule,
            final HttpServletRequest httpRequete,
            final HttpServletResponse httpReponse, Model model) {
}
```

And in my javascript, i've this URL :

POST `http://localhost:8080/project/pages/rest/consultation/bulletinhorscontrat/init/filter/nom=test 404 (Introuvable)`

I got a page not found

I've tried it with GET and i got the same error

What i've forgot in my Spring MVC Method ?

Thank's

Comment: Could you provide any logs with error description?

Comment: In my log file i dont have error, i got only this in browser : 
Erreur Web n° : 404
Navigateur : Mozilla
Adresse : ../../pages/rest/consultation/bulletinhorscontrat/init/filter/nom=COTREZ
Description :
Etat HTTP 404 -
type Rapport d''état

message

description La ressource demandée n''est pas disponible.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.59

Comment: To check error details, set spring log level to DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

With post method you can't pass variable on the link, you should use `@RequestBody` instead.

But in your case Get method should do the work but even so you need to change the link format, here the new link :

```
http://localhost:8080/project/pages/rest/consultation/bulletinhorscontrat/init/filter?nom=t&matricule=mat
```

Remove the last / from the link because it makes no sense and change POST to Get:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/init/filter", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public final Reponse filterGrid(
            @RequestParam(value = "nom", required = false) final String nom,
            @RequestParam(value = "matricule", required = false) final String matricule,
            final HttpServletRequest httpRequete,
            final HttpServletResponse httpReponse, Model model) {
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your class header to verify the link you are using

Comment: @RequestMapping("/rest/consultation/bulletinhorscontrat")
public class Controleur extends ControleurRacine.

I've others method in controller, i can access them, the error isnt in controller link